# Problems installing django-1.0.2 on Windows XP

Tags: django, installation

I'm a Windows user. I tried to install django-1.0.2 final through the command prompt and it kept giving me an error in line 70:

> The error occured where u"SVN"... It couldn't get past that line.

What to do in order to be able to install django-1.0.2?

Comment: I would advise less use of capitals

Comment: Why are you shouting at me ?!?

Comment: maybe he is in china... tough to change case settings there sometimes (from my experience)

Comment: I usually remove the caps-lock key with a small flat screwdriver from all my keyboards. What a totally useless key...

Comment: @krosenvold No it's not! You can rebind it to <ESC> so you don't have you reach as far while vimming :D

Answer (score 3):

You do not have [SubVersion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) installed on your machine. You are trying to synchronize from the current production stream via SubVersion, which is a source control system, which you do not have installed.

Easiest solution - download the latest official version per the instructions at http://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Answer (score 2):

Please install a client for the [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) Version Control System. Since you are on Windows, you can also use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) which is an easy to use SVN client for Windows.

Alternately, you can download the tarball of Django 1.0.2 [directly](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.0.2/tarball/).

And please don't SHOUT on Internet forums. We hear you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, installing TortoiseSVN won't help you there cause Django's code tries to use SVN's **command line version**.

Install a command-line SVN like:

- [Slik SVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/home/)
- [CollabNet SVN Command line](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)

Answer (score 0):

What version of python are you using? I had the same error when installing on top of python 3.2 instead of 2.7. Django only works with 2.7.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3